# How to view a SAS dataset in form view via Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

## The Background

In Base SAS, you can view a SAS dataset in either "form view" or "table view"

[image: SAS Form and table Views]]

For example...

In table view, you view the entire table, showing all columns and rows.

[image: SAS table view]

in form view, you view one record (or row) at a time.

[image: SAS form view]

By default Enterprise Guide display datasets in "table view".

## The Question

Can you do the same in SAS Enterprise Guide too? (if so, how?)

Reference: [Working with VIEWTABLE](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/68089/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1otloofcbwkpnn1sfkrhh9zjl74.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a built-in method to do this.  However, as noted in [The SAS Dummy](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2014/02/17/favorite-eg-tricks-fecht/) by Chris Hemedinger (formerly of the EG development team), there is a simple custom task that can be created that does this.

See the [SAS EG Custom Tasks](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/customtasks/index.htm) documentation page, and look at the "Observation Editor" task example; that gives you the basic thing, and then you can customize it for your needs.